# Putting form associated with a controller in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, controllers

What I'm trying to do is very simple but for some reason I'm having a lot of trouble. All I want is to allow for people to sign up for a newsletter on the homepage of my web app. I have a NewsletterSubscriptionsController that has a create action that I would like to use to store people's emails. I also have a StaticPagesController with a home action. In the view for home I would like to put a form that allows for sign up. Right now I have something like this:

<%= form_for(@newsletter_subscription, url: newsletter_subscriptions_path) do |f| %> but I keep getting a first argument can not be nil error.

In my NewsletterSubscriptionsController I have two methods for new and create.

```js
def new
  @newsletter_subscription = NewsletterSubscription.new
end

def create
  @newsletter_subscription = NewsletterSubscription.new(newsletter_subscription_params)
  if @newsletter_subscription.save
    redirect to root_url
    flash[:success] = "signed up"
  else
    redirect to root_url
end
```

How can I make it so people can fill the form out on the homepage which is 'staticpages#home'

Comment: You should be having `newsletter_subscription_params` method in your controller.Do you have it?

Comment: yes sorry, i have it it's `def newsletter_subscription_params params.require(:newsletter_subscription).permit(:email)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting the ArgumentError when you're calling `.new` in `create`, your parameters aren't getting passed successfully. Check over your form to make sure it's sending the email as `params[:newsletter_subscription][:email]`, and make sure that your request is going to the correct place as designated in your router (ensure you've created the route to the `create` action for `newsletter_subscriptions`.

Also: if you're creating new `NewsletterSubscriptions` from a homepage accessed through your other controller, you don't need a `new` action for `NewsletterSubscriptionsController`, as your user already has access to the form on the homepage. Within the context you're describing, your `new` action isn't being used.

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling the new action was doing nothing, I've removed it. The error is coming in my static_pages/home.html.erb file `<%= form_for(@newsletter_subscription, url: newsletter_subscriptions_path) do |f|` So I'm guessing the issue is since @newsletter_subscription isn't being defined in my staticpages#home action, it's always going to come up nil. Any idea on how to fix that issue? I've read using NewsletterSubscription.new would make it work but some people have also said it's not a good idea. If I do that will it still be saved in my database correctly?

Comment: Yep, if you want to use @newsletter_subscription on a page rendered from the `StaticPagesController`, you'll have to create it in that action. You'd still want to actually save the subscription in its respective controller's `create`, which is what you're going to get when you submit the form in this case.

Comment: Ok, I was trying stuff out. In my `def home` action I included `@newsletter_subscription = NewsletterSubscription.new` and that seemed to work fine. I don't know if that's the rails way to do things though